# Find file in list of directories piped from output of other command

Tags: bash, unix, find, pipe, xargs

I need to find location of a file. I don't want to search entire system, and I know that the file I am looking for is in a directory related to a certain package.

So I would like to do `find dir -name "filename" > find.out` on every dir that is returned from the command `dpkg -L package_name`.

How do I do that? I think piping and `xargs` would be useful but I don't know how to tell `xargs` to be the dir to lookup in the `find` command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
find $(dpkg -L package_name) -name "filename" > find.out
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
#!/bin/bash
readarray -t DIRS < <(exec dpkg -L package_name)  ## Store file list to an array.
find "${DIRS[@]}" -name "filename" > find.out  ## Search all at once.
```

Run with

```
bash script.sh
```

Or perhaps do it with just one line anyway:

```
readarray -t DIRS < <(exec dpkg -L package_name); find "${DIRS[@]}" -name "filename" > find.out
```